# Issue with Xcode UIImageView layout. Please assist me?

Tags: uiimageview, screen, xcode4.5

I am trying to alter some image views on the front page (the first interactive view controller) of my app depending on the size of the iphone screen. I have the follow code in the first view of my app:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"];
self.view.layer.contents = (id) image.CGImage;


if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
 {
CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
if(result.height == 960)
{

    [MALE setFrame:CGRectMake(72, 20, 175, 100)];
    [MALE setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Blue Female Symbol.png"]];
    [FEMALE setFrame:CGRectMake(65, 60, 200, 120)];
    [FEMALE setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Red Male Symbol.png"]];

}

if(result.height == 1136)
{
    [MALE setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 100, 175, 100)];
    [MALE setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Red Male Symbol.png"]];
    [FEMALE setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 300, 175, 100)];
    [FEMALE setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Blue Female Symbol.png"]];



}
}
```

}

Unfortunately this code appears to have no effect on the actual screen layout, and does not actually produce any UIImage views.

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why not trying to use a lunch image ?

Comment: Hi Eighth Ego, I am already using a launch image- I am not sure how it helps me though? Perhaps I was no clear enough in my question my apologies. I will update it with that in mind. Can you suggest why my code does not work?

Comment: Where are you creating the MALE and FEMALE image views? In a Storyboard or XIB? In code?

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for checking this out for me. I was creating them in the storyboard, and then linking them into the header file. Then I do that in the m file. Is it easier for me to create them in code? (Thanks for sticking with me, as you can probably tell by now this is my first Ios app and it has been a pretty steep learning curve).

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem.  My problem was that I had autolayout on.  With autolayout on it adjusts the frames for you and you can't adjust them in code yourself.  To turn it off, just click on any view in the storyboard and go to the file inspector, there should be an option under "Interface Builder Document" that has autolayout checked, just uncheck that box and you should be able to adjust the frames.

[image: It should look like this]

Doing this in storyboard will turn off autolayout for every view in the storyboard, but not views in any .xib files you may have.

I hope this solves your problem!